# I cant figure out what this SQL query is

Tags: t-sql

```
declare @loginId nvarchar(50)
set @loginId = null

select * from loginusers where LoginId = @loginId or @loginId  is null
```

If i execute that statement i get all the rows
but i dont understand how the where condition is processed here.

if `@loginId` is null then the where clause doesn't apply or what?

Comment: What part of `or @loginid is null` do you not understand?  The query logic seems quite clear.

Comment: It is just about logic try to read this: `LoginId = @loginId >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>OR<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @loginId is null` and in database `@loginId  is null` is the same as asking "is this variable equals to null?"

Comment: You should tag this as `tsql` as this is not plain SQL (variables like this are not supported in all SQL dialects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add my two cents here. I will try to explain your code line by line. It is `TSQL` so it will be processed in a procedural way.

You have:

```
1- declare @loginId nvarchar(50)
2- set @loginId = null
3- 
4- select * 
5-   from loginusers 
6-  where LoginId = @loginId 
7-     OR @loginId  is null
```

1. The first line (1) you defined the variable `@loginId` and its type
2. The second line (REMEMBER THAT ONE, it will be important) you assigned the value `NULL` to your variable `@loginId`

Then in your query, what it really matters it the `WHERE` clause and you use `LoginId = @loginId OR @loginId  is null` what you are asking here is:

**Is my table field `LoginId` equals to my defined variable `@loginId` OR is it equals to `NULL`**

Here you must remember the logic table OR

```
A | B | Result (A OR B)
0   0         0
1   0         1 
0   1         1
1   1         1
```

So, remember when I said that the assigned value would be important? Here is it, your database field `LoginId` will most probably not have null values and your variable (IF THERE ARE ANY CODE in between the assigning and the query) will always be `NULL`, therefore in the logic table it will be `0 or 1 = TRUE` so your where condition will always be `TRUE` which you get you all rows in that table.

Hope it help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code first sets the variable `@loginId` to `null`, and later the `where` accepts all rows with some condition **or** `@loginId is null`, so there you have it...

Answer (score 0):

"if @loginId is null then the where clause doesn't apply"

Yes, that's what this is doing. I use a similar approach for stored procedures with several parameters, where one or more of them might have a NULL value (I try to stick to less than 5 as a rule of thumb, otherwise it becomes a candidate for dynamic SQL instead).

For example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    LoginUsers
WHERE
    (@Username IS NULL OR LoginUsers.Username = @Username)
    AND (@LoginID IS NULL OR LoginUsers.LoginID = @LoginID)
```

Comment: Use caution when using this pattern;  it typically doesn't lead to optimal plans.  I've seen cases where developers get in the habit of writing SQL like this, even though they always supply a parameter because it makes the code more "extensible" in their mind.